# Designing a front facing website using Dreamweaver

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, web, design

I know similar questions have been asked in the past, but I wanted to make sure I fully understood some things, or could be pointed in the right direction.

I am new to SharePoint and SharePoint administration, and eventually we will be moving our corporate Internet sites into the system, and using it for our external facing websites.  We currently use the O365, hosted, solution, and so the migration is something I am looking into comprehending.

My inquiry involves the actual design of the new site.  I am well-versed in Dreamweaver, and before proposing we get this for my needs here at my company, I wanted to verify that we could use it in connection with SharePoint.  I have seen some things say we can upload designs, but can't seem to find how it's done, or validation that it is truly doable.  Admittedly I think SharePoint Designer is a pretty mediocre product for designing, and would like to be able to use my comfort zone if possible.

I have reached out to this community before, and gotten superb results, and it is why I came here again.

Thanks all!

Comment: The following article might give you a better idea of what's possible with regard to using Dreamweaver for SharePoint designs: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/27/using-dreamweaver-and-design-manager-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can design in whatever, but you'll need SPD or Visual Studio to turn those comps into proper master pages and page layouts. Consider Dreamweaver an extension tool of Photoshop in that it helps build the wires and comps for the design phase. Implementation of that design, you'll need SPD or VS.

Comment: Yeah, Dreamweaver is fine for an html editor, and you can use it for that with Sharepoint, but you'll need something beefier for Sharepoint that will deal with Sharepoint's own asp.net code - Visual Studio or Sharepoint Designer.  If you haven't tried Visual Studio yet, you ought to.  It's not so bad.

Comment: Interesting.  So normally what alterations need to be made in Visual Studio or SPD in order to convert it to the proper type of package?  I am assuming this isn't something that you can just import in, click some magical buttons, and poof, you're golden.

BTW many thanks to the above two commenters.

Comment: Dreamweaver pages are pretty static and you have to take into account all the other components of Sharepoint's rendering process. Site columns and content types need to be created and then associated with page layouts and then those fields need merged into the page layout. Waldek's link above looks like it's promising for 2013 but being on O365 I don't think it'll be as beneficial for you.

Comment: Well my reason for initially asking is for external/front facing websites at first.  We are importing our current websites into O365, and into SharePoint, so I figured I would look at what options I had of coding/designing everything before jumping into the deep end on it.